# Angular 8 RXJS Interval with showing and hiding element

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem with RXJS logic. I would like to create an interval with changing values of my Subject.
The case is I would like to show an element on the page, after 5 seconds. It should be shown for 10 seconds, after that it disappears. After next 5 seconds, it should appear once again, and so on, disappeared after 10 seconds.
For example if I set option to show popup after 5 seconds from page load, my popup appears for 10 seconds, after that it disappears. 5 seconds later it should show again, and so on. I have no idea how to make it work, because timings can be for example:

1. After 5 seconds show element.
2. After 5 seconds hide element.

So second subscription should wait, until previous one finished and changed its value.

This is my code I currently implemented:

```
private _shouldPopupShow$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public shouldPopupShow$ = this._shouldPopupShow$.asObservable();

    public addPopupMessage() {
        this._shouldPopupShow$.pipe(
          startWith(0),
          switchMap(() => timer(5000)),
          repeat()
        ).subscribe(() => {
          this._shouldPopupShow$.next(true);
          this._shouldPopupShow$.pipe(
            startWith(0),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            repeat(),
            switchMap(() => timer(10000))
          ).subscribe(() => {
            this._shouldPopupShow$.next(false);
          });
        });
        }
```

In my code, I would like to start changing value to true, after 5 seconds first to true. After 10 seconds, set it to false. After next 5 seconds, set it to true, after 10 seconds, set it to false and so on.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should be working:

```
const shouldPopupBeShown$: Observable<boolean> = timer(5000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => merge(of(true), timer(10000).pipe(mapTo(false)))),
  repeat()
);
```

EDIT: it does --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-v8frj3?file=index.ts

Comment: Trying to wrap your head around rxjs will take time but is worth it :) ! Good luck and glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution using `interval`

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public shouldPopupShow$ = interval(5000).pipe(
  map(i => i%2 === 0),
);
```

[Visualization on RxViz](https://rxviz.com/v/qJy4XlaO)